# How to replace certain values with their column name

Tags: r

I have a following table in R

```
df <- data.frame('a' = c(1,0,0,1,0),
                 'b' = c(1,0,0,1,0),
                 'c' = c(1,1,0,1,1))
df
   a  b  c
1  1  1  1
2  0  0  1
3  0  0  0
4  1  1  1
4  0  0  1
```

What I want is to replace the row value with the column name whenever the row is equal to 1. The output would be this one:

```
   a  b  c
1  a  b  c
2  0  0  c
3  0  0  0
4  a  b  c
4  0  0  c
```

How can I do this in R? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use `Map` and `replace`:

```
df[] <- Map(function(n, x) replace(x, x == 1, n), names(df), df)
df
#   a b c
# 1 a b c
# 2 0 0 c
# 3 0 0 0
# 4 a b c
# 5 0 0 c
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use

```
df[] <- names(df)[(NA^!df) * col(df)]
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
df
#  a b c
#1 a b c
#2 0 0 c
#3 0 0 0
#4 a b c
#4 0 0 c
```

Comment: @dash2 `!df` return a logical matrix with TRUE for 0 and FALSE for 1.  By taking NA^, the 0 values gets populated with NA. which we replace later

Comment: Deep Magic. Write R Like Perl.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `stack` and `unstack`

```
a=stack(df)
a
   values ind
1       1   a
2       0   a
3       0   a
4       1   a
5       0   a
6       1   b
7       0   b
8       0   b
9       1   b
10      0   b
11      1   c
12      1   c
13      0   c
14      1   c
15      1   c
a$values[a$values==1]=as.character(a$ind)[a$values==1]
unstack(a)
  a b c
1 a b c
2 0 0 c
3 0 0 0
4 a b c
5 0 0 c
```

Answer (score 2):

We can try iterating over the names of the data frame, and then handling each column, for a base R option:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,0,0,1,0), b=c(1,0,0,1,0), c=c(1,1,0,1,1))

df <-  data.frame(sapply(names(df), function(x) {
    y <- df[[x]]
    y[y == 1] <- x
    return(y)
}))

df

  a b c
1 a b c
2 0 0 c
3 0 0 0
4 a b c
5 0 0 c
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `ifelse`, but you have to do some intermediate transposing to account for R's column-major order processing.

```
data.frame(t(ifelse(t(df)==1,names(df),0)))
  a b c
1 a b c
2 0 0 c
3 0 0 0
4 a b c
5 0 0 c
```